# How to bypass Windows 10's auto shutdown on "Critical battery level" when the battery is dead?

Tags: windows-10, battery, power-options

If your battery is “critically low” in Windows 10, you get about 45 seconds before it will automatically shut down “for your own good.”
Well, if you have a computer with a bad battery, your computer is now perpetually in the state of having a critically low battery. AND should you want to change this setting, you’d better hope you have another computer around to research the fix, because once again, you have 30-45 seconds to fix it. And then you restart and try again. And again. And again.

There is also no option in Power Options > Advanced settings > Battery to tell it to do nothing when it’s critically low. The only options are Sleep, Shutdown or Hibernate. Critical battery level also cannot be set to 0%.

Comment: Well on Win10 you get battery low on 10% followed by battery very low on 7%, and finally battery empty on 5%. You can go to the control panel and drop the battery empty threshold down to 1% with the action "hibernation" - that way the computer will run till it dies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You’ll be needing to run this particular command in an elevated command prompt (Start > type "command" > right-click, Run as Administrator):

```
powercfg -setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_BATTERY BATACTIONCRIT 0
```

This gives you the "Do nothing" option for the computer to not Shutdown/Sleep/Hibernate even when it's at the "Critical battery level" Since you don't have more than 30-45 seconds at a time to do anything, typing it all in will be very hard.

Ready for the expert tip?

Remove the battery.

It’s kind of like car safety inspections in my state: you don’t need a windshield, but if you have one, it cannot have a crack in it, because a windshield with a crack in it can’t contain you as well in the event of a wreck.

Comment: This actually may depend on the machine. I can **NOT** do this on my laptop, in fact.  Plus, I think later updates may cause this method to be blocked.  The only available method is to lower the *battery empty* threshold down to **1%**.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me on LTSC 1809