# Laptop Hibernate every time switch to "not charging" because of wrecked battery (0% available)

Tags: laptop, battery, power, hibernate

Recently, my Asus laptop's battery wrecked: 2 days ago, my battery reached 79%, I thought the battery led indicator would turn from red to white soon, but then boom, battery turned to 0%, then I knew it wrecked after 5 years of usage.

[image: Battery wrecked]

Well, I can live without battery, but every time the battery switch from "charging" (which is a lie, it's not charging one bit) to "not charging", the laptop goes to Hibernate (laptop completely shutdown, but when you press the power button, you can get back to where you left). The problem is every time I start the laptop, the battery mode is "charging", so my laptop goes Hibernate in the middle of every of my working session.

I have thought of some solutions:

1. Replace the battery --> I don't plan to replace the battery for now, I never use my laptop on battery mode anyway.
2. Throw away the battery, leave the laptop missing battery --> I don't know if it's safe, what if there is electric shock, maybe the wrecked battery can still act as a shield, and the battery can prevent dust getting inside.
3. Living with the wrecked battery. I'm finding a way to prevent the Hibernate happens in the middle of every of my working session. Is there anyway I can start the laptop with "not charging" mode?

Concerning point #3, I just found out there is an option to disable the Hibernate:

Power Options > Battery > Critical Battery Action > Switch from "Hibernate" to "Do nothing".

[image: WindowsBatteryNoHibernateOnCritical.png]

I'll test this solution for a while, if it works.

Concerning point #2, I see that some people already did that:

[How to bypass Windows 10's auto shutdown on “Critical battery level” when the battery is dead?](https://superuser.com/a/1265275/525666)

Maybe it's not a bad solution.

Comment: Replace the battery. The charger is not designed to run the computer, it is designed to charge the battery. If the battery is not working, then 'random' will happen.

Comment: @Tetsujin : Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't replace battery, at least not when the Corana virus is run like wildfire outside. I'm finding a way to live with the wrecked battery. Assume the laptop is too old that can find no replace part.

Comment: Have you inspected the battery to check it's not swollen up or anything like that? If there is something very wrong with it then leaving it in the laptop could be a mistake

Comment: @JamesP - currently I see that it's not swollen up, I'll keep my eyes peeled. I'm ready to run my laptop on "batery-missing mode" only when my important work is completed.

Comment: @Tetsujin The power brick is intended to run the laptop and charge the battery, which can be verified by checking the wattage of the brick and matching that to the maximum power load of the laptop: V*A=W _([Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law): V[olts] x A[mps] = W[atts])_. Anything that uses a rechargeable battery, from a car to a laptop, shouldn't be powered on without the battery installed, as one of the functions of the battery is to absorb voltage spikes while the charger _(alternator in cars)_ is connected.

Comment: @123iamking Laptop batteries have a finite lifespan, usually ~100 - 200 charge/discharge cycles. It's likely the battery has dropped one or more cells and you can find battery replacements from laptop battery manufacturers that are much cheaper than buying from the laptop's OEM _(if you replace it, ensure you buy from a seller that provides a 1yr warranty)_. The screenshot in your question is how to solve your hibernation issue, however you'll also need to change the battery actions under _Battery_ at the bottom of the _Advanced Power Settings_.

Comment: @JW0914 - yup, I know how it works, that's why I said what I did. That's why under peak loads, the battery will lose charge even with the charger attached.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's not a definitive, as it depends on the wattage output of the charger _(the charger should output enough wattage to cover peak loads without pulling from the battery as there's already enough wattage supplied)_ and whether the OS has been configured with software/firmware that only begins charging the battery at a certain percentage and stops at a certain percentage _(e.g. Dell incorporates software for this since charging the battery to only 80% extends the lifecycle by ~100 charge/discharge cycles & providing continual charging wattage to the battery shortens it's lifespan)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested for a few days and see that this solution works:

There is an option to disable the Hibernate when Battery switch from "charging" to "not charging":

Power Options > Battery > Critical Battery Action > Switch from "Hibernate" to "Do nothing".
[image: "Critical Battery Action" Option Tutorial Image]

Also there's still 2 solutions worth considering:

**Replace Battery:** Of course replacing battery is better than buying a new laptop, but if the laptop's other parts may be broken soon, then just live with the dead battery until the laptop is completely broken, then buy a new laptop. In my case, it's too risky to go outside buying stuff now because the Coronavirus is spreading like wildfire outside.

**Remove Battery:** If the battery is swollen up then must remove it for your own safety, if you see that laptop works just fine with battery-missing, then go for it. I see that it works for someone, for example, [this guy](https://superuser.com/a/1265275/525666) argues:

> User seizethecarp said:
>
> Ready for the expert tip?
>
> Remove the battery.
>
> It’s kind of like car safety inspections in my state: you don’t need a
> windshield, but if you have one, it cannot have a crack in it, because
> a windshield with a crack in it can’t contain you as well in the event
> of a wreck.